# typeORM with nestjs : return type of find method

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am using : nestJS, typescript, typeORM, postgresQL

I want to check if the input password is same with the data in db.

This is how I define User entity.

```
// User.entity.ts

import {Entity, PrimaryColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryColumn({unique : true})
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @Column({unique : true})
    nickname: string;
}
```

It doesn't matter with find method.

```
async signIn(email : string, nickname : string, password : string) {
      const repo = getRepository('User');
      const user  = await repo.findOne(email);
      console.log(user);
}


> User { email: 'wasabi@mail.com', password: 'pass', nickname: 'wasabi' }
```

And I tried it these way and failed.

1. result : `Error : Property "password" does not exist on type "unknown"`

```
// *.service.ts
import {User} from '*/User.entity.ts'

async signIn(email : string, pass : string) {
      const repo = getRepository('User');
      const user = await repo.findOne(email);
      if (user.password = pass)
         console.log("right");
      else
         console.log("wrong");
}
```

2. result : `Error : Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<User>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]`

```
// *.service.ts
import {User} from '*/User.entity.ts'

async signIn(email : string, password : string) {
      const repo = getRepository('User');
      const user : Promise<User> = await repo.findOne(email);
      if (user.password = pass)
         console.log("right");
      else
         console.log("wrong");
}
```

Comment: btw if you type `user` as `Promise<User>`, then `user` will be treated as a Promise, not as an instance of `User`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happen because with `getRepository('User')` there's no way to infer which entity this repository is referring to. Use `getRepository(User)` instead and then you'll see that `repo` is `Repository<User>`, not `Repository<unknown>`

Or, you could use `User` as a type: `getRepository<User>('User')` if you don't want to import the class `User`.

btw this is TypeScript stuff. Learn more about [Generics Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types)